# How to parse web service respnse in android

Tags: android, web-services, response

In my application when I am sending request to server, I am getting response.Here I am using Soap WebService .How to read this response from my android application.Here response is in which format Json or xml ?

```
response from server is :

anyType 
{ 
schema=anyType 
{ 
  element=anyType 
         { 
        complexType=anyType 
          { 
      choice=anyType 
            { 
        element=anyType 
             { 
         complexType=anyType 
              { 
          sequence=anyType 
              { 
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; 
element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; 
}; 
}; 
}; element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; 
}; 
}; 
}; element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; 
}; 
}; 
}; element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; 
diffgram=anyType 
{NewDataSet=anyType 
{Table=anyType 
{ObjectID=b4f3ace4-2bad-4c5d-aa8e-01041a8c3f35; 
OrgUnitID=356; 
AssignToOUon=2010-07-16T06:27:13-04:00; 
ComponentID=1; 
Description=Reference (Classroom Course); 
ContentType=Reference (Classroom Course); 
IconPath=Images\classroomcourse.gif; 
 IsContent=true; 
ObjectTypeID=28; 
ContentTypeThumbNail=tn_classroomcourse.gif; 
ContentID=b4f3ace4-2bad-4c5d-aa8e-01041a8c3f35; 
Name=Advanced Clinical Practice Quarter; 
ShortDescription=A clinical practicum experience that will focus on advanced, applied clinical laboratory techniques and concepts. The practicum experience will be individually designed for each student. The student will participate in choosing the practicum site.; 
Version=1; 
StartPage=http://clsonline.uc.edu/pages/academics/?course_descriptions#cls13; CreatedUserID=5999; 
CreatedDate=2010-07-16T06:26:56.58-04:00; 
Keywords=clinical laboratory; 
Downloadable=false; 
PublishedDate=2010-07-16T06:27:02.22-04:00; Status=Published; CMSGroupID=1648; 
LongDescription=anyType{}; MediaTypeID=6; eCommBussinessRule=0; SalePrice=0.00; FolderPath=B4F3ACE4-2BAD-4C5D-AA8E-01041A8C3F35; Author=James  Rawson; ViewType=1; WindowProperties=status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,left=10,top=10,width=750,height=470; Currency=          ; SCOID=16290; Active=true; E
```